# SQL query to Extract data from smaller table to populate a column on the bigger table

Tags: sql

I would like to make a query so that I can pull data from Table 2 to populate the whole of column 3 on table 1 a bit like a vlookup in excel. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Thanks

### Table 1

[image: Table 1]

### Table 2

[image: Table 2]

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use. Also clarify what you want. Do you want to update the table or just a select query? Also post the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, this is a bad idea.  You can just lookup the value:

```
select t1.*, t2.teamname
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.teamid = t2.dim_co_team_ssk;
```

You can even hide this logic as a view.

Storing the team name in two places violates the principles of normalized databases -- which is why you have dimension tables to begin with.  The data can get out-of-synch over time.  But you can do it with an update:

```
update table1
    set name = (select t2.teamname
                from table2 t2
                where table1.teamid = t2.dim_co_team_ssk
               );
```